# Show that $\alpha \wedge \beta \in \bigwedge^2(V^*)$ is $ \alpha \wedge \beta (u, v) = \alpha(u)\beta(v) - \alpha(v)\beta(u), $

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space.

**Part a.**

Prove that there is a canonical isomorphism
$\bigwedge^k(V^*) \rightarrow \bigwedge^k(V)^*,$
given by
$
v^*_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v^*_k \longmapsto \left(u_1 \wedge \dots \wedge u_k \longmapsto \det(v^*_i(u_j))\right).
$

**Part b.**

Use part (a) to show that $\bigwedge^k(T)^* = \bigwedge^k(T^*)$ for a linear map $T : V \rightarrow W$.

**Part c.**

Let $\alpha, \beta \in V^* \cong \bigwedge^1(V^*) \cong A^1(V)$. Show that $\alpha \wedge \beta \in \bigwedge^2(V^*)$, viewed as an element of $\bigwedge^2(V^*) \cong A^2(V)$, is given by
$
\alpha \wedge \beta (u, v) = \alpha(u)\beta(v) - \alpha(v)\beta(u),
$
for all $u, v \in V$.

**My solution and ideas:**

*I already proved part a.*

*For part b.*

since $T: V\to W$ is linear, then it induces a linear map $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ given by $T^*(w^*)(v)=w^*(T(v))$ and then this last map induces a linear map $\bigwedge^k(T^*): \bigwedge^k(W^*)\to \bigwedge^k(V^*)$.

For the another hand, I know that $T: V\to W$ induces a linear map $\bigwedge^k(T)^*: \bigwedge^k(W)^*\to \bigwedge^k(V)^*$.

Knowing that $\bigwedge^k(W^*)\cong \bigwedge^k(W)^*$ and $\bigwedge^k(V^*)\cong \bigwedge^k(V)^*$, why is $\bigwedge^k(T)^* = \bigwedge^k(T^*)$ true?

*For part c.*

Why is $
\alpha \wedge \beta (u, v) = \alpha(u)\beta(v) - \alpha(v)\beta(u),
$ given by that determinant? here is some kind of uniqueness applied?

I already know that this definition is antisymmetric and bilinear, so, are they using the universal property of the wedge product?

Comment: Doesn’t c) follow immediately from a)?

Comment: Can you explain why please?

Comment: Note that $(\alpha\wedge\beta)(u,v) = (\alpha\wedge\beta)(u\wedge v)$. Why?

Comment: I guess $A^2(V)$ is the space of alternating maps $V \times V \to K$ ($K$ being the underlying field). For what you have here, it's important that $A^2(V) \cong \bigwedge^2 (V)^*$, so that you can indeed directly use a).